# Javascript String replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I wanted to know how to do the following function in javascript or jquery!
There is a function which will return the following string. I have to write a function which would convert the input given to it as shown below.

```
Hello world&nbsp;<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="36x36/1f31e.png">&nbsp;How are you all! ! ! !<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="36x36/1f33b.png">&nbsp;All the Best<img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="" src="36x36/1f4aa.png">
```

If the above is my string input!
I want the output to be like

```
Hello world&nbsp;1f31e&nbsp;How are you all! ! ! !1f33b&nbsp;1f4aa
```

How to do this.. Please suggest me a best possible way!

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Place the text inside another div and use `.text()`, here you can found more info.: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: you can parse it manually, get the number from the img.src  and concatenate it with the text

Comment: replace image nodes with text nodes.

Comment: How to do that? @KevinB
I am a newbie here

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do `$('body').text()` if you had no encoded characters but unfortunately `$.text()` automatically decodes them. So in order to get around it, you would need to write a custom function.

```
$.fn.getText = function()
{
  var text = '';
  $(this).contents()
    .filter(function() {
       $(this).text() == "" ? text += "&nbsp;" + $(this).attr("src").split('/')[1].split('.')[0]  : text += $(this).text();
    });
    return text;
}

alert($('body').getText());
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2rhasve1/1/